# Best way to load images from directory if numpy and cv2 preprocessing is required

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to create a dataset but I'm running into a couple of problems

- I can't insert a numpy/cv2 preprocessing step before conversion to tensors. I can use tf.data.Dataset.map but that means I have to unbatch, convert to numpy array, do the preprocessing ... and so on. I tried this but I keep running into little bugs that are fixable, but I'm getting the feeling it wasn't designed to be used this way.
- I don't have much control over the way the train/val split is done. I want to do do a particular KFold splitting.

FYI I'm used to doing this in PyTorch via custom Datasets and DataLoaders.

Comment: The ``tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory``, [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) gets a ``preprocessing_function`` which may be useful

Comment: @Kaveh excellent! And using `flow_from_dataframe` gives me the flexibility I need for defining splits (I just split the dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `preprocessing_function` argument, in `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` to pass your preprocessing function to the generator in order to apply on each sample.

Reference: [Image Data Generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)